How to make a graphical abstract in landscape page in elsevier elsearticle?
The default elsarticle graphical abstract gets inserted into the document as portrait page. How to add it in landscape mode in elsevier elsearticle?

Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates, what you've tried to far and also your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. BTW: elsarticle is a publisher class. Such classes are usually not designed for general documents. So if you want to submit your article, are you sure, that the publisher would like landscape pages in an article? AFAIK usually not.
